# Is there a precursor to the Culture?

Tags: dystopia, the-culture, iain-m-banks

The Culture, from the Iain M Banks novels, seems to be a merger between a utopia and a dystopia. Is this a new phenomenon or do other examples exist?

Comment: Is this a question about the source cultures of the Culture (discussed from time to time---there are several) or about earlier High Level Involved powers?

Comment: No, I mean in literature. E.g. Ashers Commonwealth is also half utopia half dystopia but it is published later than The culture.

Comment: BTW--I don't really buy the Culture as dystopian. Conflicted, sure. Trapped between their image of themselves and a galaxy that is often Not Nice (tm), absolutely. Not ideal for everyone, yup. But not dystopian. Not when people can and *do* leave either a little bit or wholesale.

Comment: Isn't this basically a recommendation question then?  I think we may want to try out [this](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/q/764/1027) suggested methodology to answer the question.

Comment: I think the _very existence_ of Jernau 'Morat' Gurgeh renders the culture dystopian.

Comment: @aquaherd but, Gurgeh wasn't culture though?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[*Utopia*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Utopia_%28book%29) by Thomas More, which coined the word and created the concept, but in fact has some dystopian elements as well (especially if you're a devout Catholic, as most people were at the time).

And before that, [*The Republic*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Republic_%28Plato%29) by Plato.

Comment: Great answer! I assumed that utopias in literature were always spotless and dystopias always bleak. I didn't see any dystopian aspects in Thomas Morus' Utopia when I read it - must reread it with the devout Catholic glasses on.

Answer (score 3):

How about Brave New World? Or Orson Scott Card's Worthing Saga. (Note that I also don't agree with the characterization of the Culture as dystopian.)

Comment: Brave new World is a pure dystopia, isn't it?

Comment: I would agree with aquaherd, I'm not sure there is much Utopia there.

Comment: @TobyAllen quoting from wikipedia on the society: "an eternally peaceful, stable global society in which goods and resources are plentiful [...] and everyone is happy." Sounds somewhat utopian to me.

Comment: By the purely materialistic definition, BNW is a utopia in that the majority of citizens (including Epsilons) experience no hardship in material wealth or through societal instability.  Whether the system is equitable is another matter.